# Build pages with slug.html rather than slug/index.html in Jekyll (ugly URLs)

Tags: jekyll

I have a page with the slug `about-us`. By default, Jekyll builds this:

```
/about-us
         /index.html
```

However, I want this instead:

```
/about-us.html
```

Reading through the [Permalinks](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) documentation, it looked like I could use this in the config

```
permalink: /:slug:output_ext
```

However, this produces the same output as above.

How I configure Jekyll to write the pages as their own .html page, rather than in a folder with an index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll only generates `/about-us/index.html` if you've `permalink: /about-us/` in the **page's front matter** or if you've `permalink: pretty` in your **config file**.

Ensuring neither of the above conditions should generate `/about-us.html`

Comment: Ooh! Will check the `permalink`s now and report back.